# How to make a textbox appear when turning off a Smartphone?

Tags: android, testing

I'm writing a simple app for Android. It's very simple yet, it just take as input a username and a password.

I need to store those user and pwd firstly, then I need to make a textbox asking for those user and password appear when I try to turn off the smartphone.
Could you please help me on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this reliably.  Even if there was a systemwide shutdown message (and I don't think there is), the user could always just pull the battery.  Or hold the power button for a few seconds to force a reboot.

Even ignoring that-  there's no way to make shutdown wait until a user has entered the info you want.  Even if you could display it, it would just go away and the phone would turn off.  You'd be looking at a custom android os to do this.

Comment: yeah ok, but what if I would just wanted to make a message appear when you try to turn off the phone?

Comment: Same issues.  If I'm wrong and their is a systemwide event that gets published maybe you could display it for less than a second before it goes away.  Depending on the order that deinit happens in.  But it won't be reliable, and it won't stop the OS from powering off the device.